# Cloudformation EC2 run command lines after each update

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to have my cloudformation file trigger some commands after the EC2 instance has been deployed.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Reports

Parameters:
  AmiID:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>
    Description: "The ID of the AMI."
    Default: /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2

Resources:
  WebAppInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref AmiID
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref WebAppSecurityGroup
      UserData:
        'Fn::Base64': |-
          #!/usr/bin/env bash
          curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
          python3 get-pip.py --user
          pip install Flask
          aws s3 sync s3://project-pi-reports-codepipeline-bucket/ /home/ec2-user/project-pi-reports
          set FLASK_APP=hello 
          flask run /home/ec2-user/project-pi-reports

      IamInstanceProfile:
        Ref: ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile

  ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - Ref: ListS3BucketsRole

  ListS3BucketsRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"

  ListS3BucketsPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: ListS3BucketsPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - s3:*
            Resource: "*"
      Roles:
        - Ref: ListS3BucketsRole

  WebAppSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Join ["-", [webapp-security-group, dev]]
      GroupDescription: "Allow HTTP/HTTPS and SSH inbound and outbound traffic"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 5000
          ToPort: 5000
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  WebAppEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
      InstanceId: !Ref WebAppInstance
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ["-", [webapp-eip, dev]]

Outputs:
  WebsiteURL:
    Value: !Sub http://${WebAppEIP}
    Description: WebApp URL
```

What I basically want, once the EC2 instance is updated through CodePipeline, to download the latest files from s3 and then start a flask server.

I've added those lines into my cloudformation file, under the UserData but it only runs the first time it creates the instance, but not when it triggers a stack update.

Is there any way, I can just have those commands run on each update?

Answer (score 0):

> it only runs the first time it creates the instance, but not when it triggers a stack update.

Yes. That's how UserData works. But if you can restart an instance after each update in your pipeline, you can make UserData run at every restart as explained in [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/).

> Is there any way, I can just have those commands run on each update?

Yes. This is usually done by [AWS CodeDeploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html), which would be part of your CI/CD pipeline. Alternatively, in your pipeline you can use [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) to run arbitrary code on you instance. This off course would need to be added to your pipeline as well.